# renderしたはずのページが表示されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

## 環境

Ruby on Rails 6
Amazon Linux2
Amazon EC2

## 問題が起こった経緯

動画サイトでの検索→検索結果画面表示の途中で問題が起きました。
１．共通レイアウト内の検索フォームを使って検索
２．検索機能（search）で検索：
ファイル名（:key）またはカテゴリー名（:category）で動画テーブルをWhere
３．検索機能（search）で検索結果画面をrender
４．検索結果画面（search_result）：検索結果を一覧表示

## 問題

renderしたはずの検索結果画面（search_result）が表示されません。

```
Rendered s3files/search_result.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.8ms | Allocations: 628)
```

代わりにrootURLに設定したホーム画面が表示されます。
ログインしていなかったためrootに遷移されたわけでもありませんでした。
初めての類の問題で困っております。

## 関連ファイル

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 's3files#home'
  resources :users do
    resources :channels
  end
  get 's3files/home', to: 's3files#home'
  get 's3files/music', to: 's3files#music'
  get 's3files/movie', to: 's3files#movie'
  get 's3files/program', to: 's3files#program'
  get 's3files/game', to: 's3files#game'
  get 's3files/news', to: 's3files#news'
  get 's3files/sports', to: 's3files#sports'
  get 's3files/learning', to: 's3files#learning'
  post 's3files/search', to: 's3files#search'
  get 's3files/search_result', to: 's3files#search_result'
  resources :s3files
  resources :comments
  resources :sessions, only: %i[create]
end
```

##s3files_controller.rb

```
class S3filesController < ApplicationController
  
  skip_before_action :check_logged_in
  
  ------------------------省略------------------------

  def home
    @s3files = S3file.all
    @trend = S3file.joins(:one_day_view).order(count: :desc).limit(10)
  end

  ------------------------省略------------------------
  
  def search
    if params[:key]
      @s3files = S3file.where(key: params[:key])
    else params[:category]
      @s3files = S3file.where(key: params[:key])
    end
    render 'search_result'
  end
    
  
  def search_result
  end
  
  private
  ------------------------省略------------------------

    def s3file_params
      params.require(:s3file).permit(:key, :image, :category, :channel_id)
    end

  ------------------------省略------------------------
end
```

### application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stream</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
   <header>
      <% if current_user %>
        <%= link_to(current_user.name, current_user) %>
      <% else  %>
        <%= link_to "ゲストログイン(閲覧用)", sessions_path, method: :post %>
      <% end %>
      <%= render 's3files/search_form' %>
    </header>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

##_search_form.erb

```
<h2>検索フォーム</h2>
<%= form_with(model: S3file.new, url: '/s3files/search') do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :key %> 
  <%= form.text_field :key %>
  <%= form.label :category %> 
  <%= form.text_field :category %>
  <%= form.submit "検索" %>
<% end %>
```

### search_result.html.erb

```
<h1>検索結果</h1>
<% @s3files.each do |s3file| %>
  <p>チャンネル名：<%= s3file.channel.name %></p>
  <p>動画タイトル：<%= s3file.key %></p>
  <%= link_to(image_tag("https://bucket-for-stream.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/assets#{s3file.id.to_s}/#{s3file.image}"), s3file) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
form_withの引数にlocal: trueを指定するとレンダリングされました。
Rails6.0のform_withはデフォルトでajaxという非同期通信を使ってページを表示するようです。
要はajaxという新種の描画処理を意図せず使っていたことがエラーの原因でした。